# Excel Interop: Changing Button Text

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have a large number of similarly-formatted Excel spreadsheets, each with two buttons assigned to two different macros.

The text in one button reads `Button A` and the text in the other one reads `Button B`.

I would like to change the text in `Button A` to read `Button C` for every spreadsheet programmatically.

Is this possible using the Excel Interop?

Comment: Have you googled to see any Interop examples using Buttons and Excel...?

Comment: Is this possible using the Excel Interop;  Yes it is

Comment: Yes, I have tried Googling it.  I have been searching for a while now.  I have found Interop solutions for every other Excel task I have needed it for, but not for modifying buttons.